# loop through an array and show results

Tags: php

i m trying to do a loop but get stacked ,

i have a function that convert facebook id to facebook name ,  by the facebook api. name is getName().

on the other hand i have an arra with ids . name is $receivers.

the count of the total receivers $totalreceivers .

i want to show names of receivers according to the ids stored in the array.
i tried every thing but couldnt get it. any help will be appreciated . thanks in advance.

here is my code :

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < $totalreceivers; $i++) {

foreach ( $receivers as $value)
   {
    echo getName($receivers[$i]) ;

     }
     }
```

the function :

```
function getName($me) 
{ 
$facebookUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$me; 
$str = file_get_contents($facebookUrl); 
$result = json_decode($str); 
return $result->name; 
}
```

Comment: why are you using a for loop and then a foreach and then referencing the variable that is not being iterated in the foreach loop?

Comment: what are you getting in the output?

Answer (score 3):

The inner foreach loop seems to be entirely redundant. Try something like:

```
$names = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalReceivers; $i++) {
   $names[] = getName($receivers[$i]);
}
```

Doing a `print_r($names)` afterwards should show you the results of the loop, assuming your getNames function is working properly.

Comment: json_decode() returns a boolean FALSE if it fails, which would show up as an empty string in the loop. Add some error checking to the getName function.

Comment: im getting Array ( ) as result with print_r($names). how can i add check error ?

Comment: What's $totalReceivers? even if getName wasn't returning anything, the loop would still cause at least `$totalReceivers` worth of empty strings/nulls be assigned to the array. the fact that you get an empty array suggests to me that $totalReceivers isn't set right.

Comment: $totalreceivers is this : $q1 = mysql_query("select receiverid1,receiverid2,receiverid3,receiverid4,receiverid5,receiverid6,receiverid7,receiverid8,receiverid9,receiverid10 from invitations where senderid = '$id' ",$d1);

$row = mysql_fetch_row($q1); 
$totalreceivers = count(array_filter($row));

Comment: array_filter without a callback function is pointless, and your count could only ever be 1, since you're only fetching a single row. Most likely you want to use `mysql_num_rows()` instead to find out how many rows there are in the result set.

Comment: when i do an echo of $totalreceivers shows me 9 . i changed array_filter  to mysql_num_rows. but still sin success !!

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the content of the `$receivers` array try either

```
foreach ($receivers as $value){
   echo getName($value) ;
}
```

or

```
foreach ($receivers as $key => $value){
   echo getName($key) ;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response . t tried your code but the result is : Mark ZuckerbergChris HughesDustin MoskovitzArie Hasit  !!!!!!!!

Comment: Well, thats what `echo` does. But your loop works now so replace `echo` with something useful.

Comment: then there is something wrong with the `getName()` function. Might be that you don't have a right to query the data and so FB returns the stuff it return as a joke. or as a test data. I don't know FB's API to tell that.

Comment: when i execute getName() with single id without loop . it works fine. how can get the names without looping for each id in the array ?